# Using Urban Airship & Phonegap, can't register device: "Device token is nil"

Tags: ios, cordova, urbanairship.com

From the newest example on git hub (https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push), with a shinny new build of Phonegap/Cordova's latest v2.3.0, we're having trouble on iOS registering a device with UA. We had no problem until we updated to the latest. We're registering the device like this:

```
function on_reg(error, pushID) {
    console.log("UA Registration complete.")
}

push = window.pushNotification
push.registerEvent('registration', on_reg)
```

But every time we call that code, we get an error that says "**Device token is nil. Registration will be attempted at a later time**". Except that never happens.

Here is the log:

> 2013-01-09 17:38:29.378 Grouped[271:907] [D] -[UAPush
>   updateRegistration] [Line 589] Checking registration state
>
> 2013-01-09 17:38:29.380 Grouped[271:907] [D] -[UAPush
>   updateRegistration] [Line 609] Device token is nil. Registration will
>   be attempted at a later time
>
> 2013-01-09 17:38:29.744 Grouped[271:907] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils
>   getDeviceID] [Line 275] Retrieved device id info from keychain.
>
> 2013-01-09 17:38:29.745 Grouped[271:907] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils
>   getDeviceID] [Line 279] Device ID result is not nil.
>
> 2013-01-09 17:38:29.746 Grouped[271:907] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils
>   getDeviceID] [Line 288] Loaded Device ID:
>   C1E75722-ED34-4513-BBA5-CB9EDEBBD117
>
> 2013-01-09 17:38:29.747 Grouped[271:907] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils
>   getDeviceID] [Line 289] Loaded Model Name: iPhone4,1
>
> 2013-01-09 17:38:32.724 Grouped[271:907] [D] -[UAAnalytics
>   requestDidSucceed:response:responseData:] [Line 461] Analytics data
>   sent successfully. Status: 200

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tracked this bug down to a change that was made in the newest version of PhoneGap:

> For iOS, device.platform used to return “iPhone”, “iPad” or “iPod
>   Touch” — now it returns (correctly) “iOS”.

This was conflicting with the PushNotification.js module, returning false information:

```
// Registration

PushNotification.prototype.registerForNotificationTypes = function (types, callback) {
if(device.platform == "iPhone" || device.platform == "iPad" || device.platform == "iPod touch") {
this.call_native(callback, "registerForNotificationTypes", [types])
}
}
```

Changing this to **device.platform == "iOS"** fixes the problem.

*Urban Airship, if you want to update your git at https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push/blob/master/ios-sample/www/lib/PushNotification.js I'm sure many people would appreciate it!*

Comment: Hi, can you help me setting push notifications in phonegap using urbanairship in IOS ?